# What is "perceptual competence"?

Tags: perception, terminology, intelligence

I have no idea what **perceptual competence** is? Does anyone know about it? I found no information about it on the web.

Comment: Could you provide us with the context?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
"Perceptual competence" is "the ability to perceive".

**Background**
I Googled "perceptual competence" and the first hit was an open source article [(Lencz *et al*., 2003)](http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=207276). They define perceptual competence as:

> [The] initial representation of to-be-remembered material [in the context of [working memory]](http://www.simplypsychology.org/working%20memory.html). Perceptual competency itself can include multiple subprocesses, including sensory representation, attention, executive processes, and possibly verbal memory processes, if the stimuli are easily recognized or verbalized.

Reading their use and interpretation, I think "perceptual competence" can be simply literally semantically translated, namely:

- *[PERCEPTUAL](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptual)* - `of, relating to, or involving perception especially in relation to immediate sensory experience` and
- *[COMPETENCE](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competence)* - `the ability to do something well : the quality or state of being competent`

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lencz *et al*., *Arch Gen Psychiatry* (2003); **60**(3):238-43](http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=207276)</sub>